# Is it possible to convert words to numbers in a string without VBA?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that contains lists of numbers in string format, a bit like this.

```
1,2,3
1,2,three
4,five,6
four, five, 6
```

I would like to convert the words within the string into numbers, so that the data above would look like this:

```
1,2,3 
1,2,3
4,5,6
4,5,6
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this without using VBA please?

Comment: are those only simple figures - or do you expect sth like "three hundred forty five" as well?

Comment: @Ike they're simple; they should only go up to ten.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following approach in the past, that maybe suitable for your needs.

```
=LET(SUBST, LAMBDA(txt,tks, REDUCE(txt, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(tks), 1),
  LAMBDA(ac,idx,SUBSTITUTE(ac,INDEX(tks, 1, idx), INDEX(tks, 2, idx))))),
  SUBST("1,one,2,two,3,three", {"one","two","three";"1","2","3"}))
```

It returns: `1,1,2,2,3,3`.

It uses `REDUCE` to invoke `SUBSTITUTE` as many times as `tks` (tokens) we have. The input variable `tks` has in the first row the *old* values and in the second row the corresponding *new* values (the formula can be easily adapted to have `tks` in a column-wise array). Showing up to `three`, but you can complete the rest of `tks` with the additional values.

You can define `SUBST` as a `LAMBDA` function in [Name Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) and then use it like any other Excel standard function.

**Note:**
Here [How to find and replace multiple values at once in Excel (bulk replace)](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-find-replace-multiple-values/#:%7E:text=Find%20and%20replace%20multiple%20values%20with%20nested%20SUBSTITUTE,value%20with%20a%20new%20one.) is documented a recursive approach via the `LAMBDA` function. Check the section: *Example 1. Search and replace multiple words/strings at once*.

This solution has several limitations:

- It uses a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function) `OFFSET`
- Since it uses `OFFSET`, *you can not use arrays*, you need to have the `old`, and `new` values in a range.
- The condition for ending the recursion has an empty string in `old`, so you must ensure it.
- Since it is based on recursive `LAMBDA`, you cannot use a `LET` function (you get a `#NAME?` error). Instead, you must define it in the [Name Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67). It is a *limitation for the Excel Web version* because you cannot access the *Name Manager* for this version. You can circumvent this limitation for Excel Web by installing the Add-ins: [Advanced Formula Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/advanced-formula-environment-a-microsoft-garage-project/#:%7E:text=The%20advanced%20formula%20environment%20is,making%20them%20easier%20to%20read.) and use for example the *Module* tab.

Based on one of the approaches provided in the previous link, you can  define a `LAMBDA` function in *Name Manager* and name it for example: `MultiReplace`

```
=LAMBDA(text, old, new, IF(old="", text, 
  MultiReplace(SUBSTITUTE(text, old, new), 
    OFFSET(old, 1, 0), OFFSET(new, 1, 0))))
```

and then invoke it as follow:
[image: sample using LAMBDA recursive function]

The previous `LAMBDA` function `MultiReplace` can be modified to mitigate the limitations mentioned above, such as using `OFFSET`, so it can work with arrays also as follow:

```
= LAMBDA(text, old, new, IF(LEN(@old)=0, text, 
  MultiReplace(SUBSTITUTE(text, INDEX(old,1), INDEX(new,1)), 
    IFERROR(DROP(old,1),""), IFERROR(DROP(new,1),""))))
```

**Note**: To stop the recurrence we use the `@`-operator to get the first element, therefore when we have removed all the rows, the length will be empty.

Now we can invoke the function for arrays as follow:

```
=MultiReplace("1,one,2,two,3,three", {"one";"two";"three"}, {"1";"2";"3"})
```