# How can one sort a list of dictionaries into an excel sheet such that each unique key and one corresponding key are placed into columns?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries organized as such:

```py
listofdictionaries = [{'key1': (A, B, C), 'key2':[1, 2, 3]}, 
                      {'key1': (AA, BB, CC), 'key2':[1, 2, 3]}, 
                      {'key1': (AAA, BBB, CCC), 'key2':[4, 5, 6]}]
```

This list's first and second items have an equivalent value for key2. The third item has a different value for key2. Still using Python, I want the columns organized as such:

| Group 1 | Group 1 Items | Group 2 | Group 2 Items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 3] | (A, B, C) | [4, 5, 6] | (AAA, BBB, CCC) |
|  | (AA, BB, CC) |  |  |

In addition I would like the output to be a .csv file.

Comment: The elements inside the lists in `key2`'s values are unique or can they be repeated? Meaning, could you have {'key2': [1,1,3]}?

Comment: @ccolin They are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pandas`, you can use something like this function

```py
def groupItems(dictList, itemsFrom, groupBy, saveTo=None):
    ik, gk, colsDict = itemsFrom, groupBy, {}
    groups = {str(d.get(gk)): d.get(gk) for d in dictList} 
    itemsList = [ [d.get(ik) for d in dictList if str(d.get(gk))==g] 
                  for g in groups   ]

    maxRows = max(len(li) for li in itemsList) if groups else 0
    for gi, (g, li) in enumerate(zip(groups.keys(), itemsList), 1):
        colsDict[f'Group {gi}'] = [groups[g]] + [None]*(maxRows-1)
        colsDict[f'Group {gi} Items'] = li + [None]*(maxRows-len(li))
    
    rdf = pandas.DataFrame(colsDict)
    if saveTo and isinstance(saveTo, str):
        print('Saving', maxRows, 'rows for', len(groups),'groups to', saveTo)
        rdf.to_csv(saveTo, index=False)
    return rdf
```

Calling <kbd>**`groupItems(listofdictionaries, 'key1', 'key2', 'x.csv')`**</kbd> will save the DataFrame from the screenshot below to `x.csv`.

[image: dfop1]
**<sub>To demonstrate that the brackets were not lost:</sub>**
[image: opmd1]

---

You could also get it in [this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Wty.png) if you change the function to

```py
def groupItems(dictList, itemsFrom, groupBy, saveTo=None):
    ik, gk = itemsFrom, groupBy
    groups = {str(d.get(gk)): d.get(gk) for d in dictList} 
    itemsList = [ [d.get(ik) for d in dictList if str(d.get(gk))==g] 
                  for g in groups   ]

    maxRows = max(len(li) for li in itemsList) if groups else 0
    
    colsDict = {f'Group {gi}': [groups[g]] + [None] + (
        [f'Group {gi} Items'] + li + [None]*(maxRows-len(li))
    ) for gi, (g, li) in enumerate(zip(groups.keys(), itemsList), 1)}
    rdf = pandas.DataFrame(colsDict) 

    if saveTo and isinstance(saveTo, str):
        print('Saving', maxRows+4, 'rows for', len(groups),'groups to', saveTo)
        rdf.to_csv(saveTo, index=False)
    return rdf
```

---

###### NOTE: Saving as csv will [stringify all non-numeric cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTZ7O.png). If you want to preserve nested structure, I suggest [saving as JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) instead.

Comment: Quick note, as per question expected output, the brackets in **GroupX** columns are part of the output, so instead of `1,2,3` it should be `[1,2,3]` for example.

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks [I hadn't noticed before] but the brackets disappeared just because of how DataFrames get displayed - if you print the markdown or view the CSV, the brackets are still there

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using an Excel formula. Probably using `FILTERXML` there is shorter way, but it is not available for Excel Web, which is the version I use. In cell `B3`, you can use the following formula:

```
=LET(header, {"Group","Name"}, clean, SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(B1,
 {"[{","'key1': ","'key2':","}]","}, {"},,1),"),",")"),
 split, WRAPROWS(clean,2), gps,INDEX(split,,2),names, INDEX(split,,1),
 gpsUx, UNIQUE(gps), out, DROP(REDUCE("", gpsUx, LAMBDA(ac,x,
  HSTACK(ac, VSTACK(header, HSTACK(x, FILTER(names, gps=x)))))),,1),
 IFERROR(out,""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

An **alternative solution** is using a recursive function to do all the replacement. Please check my answer to the question: [Is it possible to convert words to numbers in a string without VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74574918/is-it-possible-to-convert-words-to-numbers-in-a-string-without-vba/74575828#74575828) I use the same function here `MultiReplace`:

```
= LAMBDA(text, old, new, IF(MIN(LEN(old))=0, text, 
  MultiReplace(SUBSTITUTE(text, INDEX(old,1), INDEX(new,1)), 
    IFERROR(DROP(old,1),""), IFERROR(DROP(new,1),""))))
```

where `old` and `new` are `nx1` arrays, where `n` is the number of substitutions.

The above function needs to be defined in the *Name Manager* since it is recursive. Now we are going to use in formula to provide the output of the question in cell `B3`:

```
=LET(header, {"Group", "Name"}, clean, MultiReplace(B1, 
  {"{'key1': " ; ", 'key2':" ; "}" ; "[(";"]]";"], ("}, 
  {"" ; "-" ; "" ; "(" ; "]" ; "] & ("}), 
 split, TEXTSPLIT(@clean,"-"," & "), gps,INDEX(split,,2),names, INDEX(split,,1), 
 gpsUx, UNIQUE(gps), out, DROP(REDUCE("", gpsUx, LAMBDA(ac,x, 
 HSTACK(ac, VSTACK(header, HSTACK(x, FILTER(names, gps=x)))))),,1), 
 IFERROR(out,""))
```

You can check the output of each name variable: `clean`, `split`, to see the intermediate results. Once we have the information in array format (`split`), then we apply `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern. Check my answer to the question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) for more details.

Both solutions work for multiple groups, not just for two groups as in the input sample. For each unique `key1` group it generates the **Group** and its corresponding **Name** columns and concatenate the result horizontally via `HSTACK`.